# Pasar data entre componentes HERMANOS?

Tags: angular

quisiera saber como pasar datos de un componente a otro, que no son hijos ni padres, por ejemplo:

Tengo un login y luego un componente home.

Yo quisiera pasarle desde el login a home un objeto. Claro no se puede hacer con input,ni output ya que no son padre e hijo,ni viceversa.
Tampoco quisiera hacerlo con localstorage, quisera manejar la informacion mas privada digamos.

No se me ocurre alguna otra forma, ya que aunque haga un servicio, el objeto no quedaria en memoria cuando se renderiza el siguiente.

No se si por rutas se puede enviar info de una ruta a la otra. (no por parametro, tipo /:id) si no pasar un objeto entero

Alguna solucion?

Comment: Sí se puede enviar info de una ruta a otra. Y los servicios, en general,  no se destruyen cuando se cambia de componente, los servicios se crean una vez y persisten a lo largo de la aplicación.

Comment: podrias dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Para la comunicación usando servicios https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service dice padre a hijo pero entre hermanos es parecido.  Pasando datos en la ruta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar datos entre componentes una forma puede ser usar un servicio con un `EventEmitter`

Te voy a poner un ejemplo donde paso una una persona de un componente a otro, te dejo la explicación del código. Al final del código explico por que esto funciona.

### **Interfaz Persona**

```js
/* Persona.ts
*
* Contiene los datos de una persona
*/
export interface Persona {
  nombre: string,
  apellido: string
}
```

### **Servicio: Servicio de Persona**

```js
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Persona } from 'src/app/interfaces/Interfaz';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ServicioPersona {

  // Creamos la persona
  persona: Persona;
  
  // Con output creamos el nuevo EventEmitter. De este objeto obtendremos los cambios.
  @Output()
  personaEmitter = new EventEmitter<Persona>();


  constructor() { }

  // Cambiamos el atributo this.persona y llamamos a cambioPersona().
  setPersona(nuevaPersona: Persona) {
    this.persona = nuevaPersona;
    this.cambiosPersona();
  }

  // Emitimos los cambio de this.persona.
  cambiosPersona() {
    this.personaEmitter.emit(this.persona);
  }
}
```

**Importante:** Ambos componentes se encuentran en app.component.html, para que se muestren los componentes en la misma pantalla, pero esto no es necesario, pueden estar en distintos componentes que no se muestren al mismo tiempo.

### **Componente1: Componente que cambia la persona**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicioPersona } from 'src/app/services/service/serviciopersona.service';
import { Persona } from 'src/app/interfaces/Interfaz';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente1',
  templateUrl: './componente1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componente1.component.scss']
})

export class Componente1Component implements OnInit {

  persona: Persona;

  constructor(private servicio: ServicioPersona) { }

  // Inicializo persona a vacío para que no me arroje un error, pero esto no es necesario realmente.
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.persona = {
      nombre: '',
      apellido: ''
    }
  }

  // Estas dos funciones funcionan exactamente igual, crean una persona y la envían al servicio. Estos métodos se llaman desde el html con un evento (click).
  cambiarPersona1() {
    this.persona = {
      nombre: 'nombre1',
      apellido: 'apellido1'
    }
    // podrías agregar un console.log() para saber que persona estas enviando en este punto en ambos métodos.
    this.servicio.setPersona(this.persona)
  
  }

  cambiarPersona2() {
    this.persona = {
      nombre: 'nombre2',
      apellido: 'apellido2'
    }

    this.servicio.setPersona(this.persona)
  }
}
```

### **Componente2: Consultar la persona**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicioPersona } from 'src/app/services/service/serviciopersona.service';
import { Persona } from 'src/app/interfaces/Interfaz';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-componente2',
  templateUrl: './componente2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componente2.component.scss']
})
export class Componente2Component implements OnInit {

  persona: Persona;

  constructor(private servicio: ServicioPersona) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Nos suscribimos al Emitter del servicio que habíamos declarado con @Output,
    // y le decimos que persona sera lo que nos devuelva el observable de personaEmitter
    this.servicio.personaEmitter.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.persona = data;
      }
    );
  }

  // Este método se llama desde un botón y nos imprime el estado actual de la persona por consola.. 
  obtenerPersona() {
    console.log(this.persona)
  }
}
```

### **Resultados**

**Caso 1:**

- Pulsamos en el botón "Cambiar a usuario 1" del `Componente1` y acto seguido pulsamos en "Obtener Usuario" del `Componente2`

Consola:

```js
{nombre: "nombre1", apellido: "apellido1"}
```

**Caso 2:**

- Partiendo del Caso 1, hacemos click en "Cambiar a usuario2 del `Componente2` y acto seguido pulsamos en "Obtener Usuario" del `Componente2`
  Consola:

```js
{nombre: "nombre2", apellido: "apellido2"}
```

#### Ahora vamos a explicar algunas cosas en mayor profundidad.

**- ¿Porque esto funciona?**
Funciona porque los servicios no se descargan en ningún momento, mientras que los componentes se cargan y descargan conforme navegas por la pagina, los servicios siempre están cargados en memoria y por tanto siempre tienen los datos.

**- ¿Que flujo siguen los datos?**
Desde el principio sería así

```
Componente1 (CambiarPersona()) -> Servicio (SetPersona(persona)) -> Servicio (CambiosPersona()) -> Componente2 (EventEmitter)
```

**- ¿Cuando se produce el cambio exactamente?**
El cambio se produce cuando estamos en el servicio y llamamos al método `emit()`. Cuando llamamos al evento, este se encarga de hacerle llegar al `EventEmitter` los datos.

**- Pero, tu lo haces en una sola dirección, ¿Puede ser bidireccional?**
Claro, los métodos están en el servicio y los puedes llamar desde donde quieras, y si guardas a la persona como un parámetro podrías acceder al html con la sintaxis de los dobles corchetes de esta forma:

```js
{{ persona.nombre }}
```

---

Espero que la respuesta te haya resultado de utilidad, y que hayas conseguido entender los conceptos básicos de una forma intuitiva. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Me parece muy interesante lo que planteas, ahora mi pregunta es, esto funciona si los componentes no esta en la misma ruta? supongamos que en la ruta /home, se renderiza el comonente home donde creo y edito a persona, y yo quiero pasar esa persona modificada a la ruta /otraRuta y consultar desde el componente que renderiza esta ruta, a la persona modificada, sirve igual?

Comment: Buenas @DiegoFerrer Si, funciona siempre, ya que lo que haces es emitir un evento cuando se produce un cambio desde cualquier componente. Ese cambio es capturado y transmitido al resto de componentes que lo vayan a usar, estén o no visibles a la vez, y esto funciona porque el que está gestionando esa información es el servicio, que al final es de donde los componentes obtienen la información a mostrar, subscribiéndose a ellos.

Comment: Para mas información con respecto a la respuesta y al comentario te dejo este enlace:
- https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter